# Need a little guidance with NFC Data Transfer

Tags: android, nfc, android-beam

Might be a dumb question. I need some guidance to write a simple app, which allows the phone to transfer the touch-input-data via its NFC to another phone (not necessarily via android beam). I've got some pretty basic questions, as I never worked on android app development. Hope this is not inappropriate.

1) Is it possible?

2) How do I get started, without spending lots of time with the android developer reference?

Thanks in advance :o)

Comment: Have you tried Googling it?

Comment: Yeah but couldn't find a direct answer anywhere, Chuck..

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correct you want kind of p2p. So you are typing something on the phone A and simultaniously get that text on phone B. If yes then short answer - it is not possible for now in android. Max that you can get for now it's 1 message to each way like it in Google Beam.

Answer (score 0):

Use Android Beam to pair the devices then transfer via bluetooth or wifi. Holding together two devices is really not very user-friendly when done by two persons.